# creating instances in objective c

Tags: objective-c, instance

Here is my code:

```
//ECHOAppDelegate.m
@implementation ECHOAppDelegate
 ...
 @end

//PtyView.m
 @interface PtyView (PtyPrivate)
 -(void)startTask;
 -(void) didRead: (NSNotification *)fileNoty;
 @end

 @implementation PtyView
 ...
 -(void)startTask {
 //starts task
 }
 @end
```

Now, how do I trigger "startTask" from ECHOAppDelegate.m? I need to create an instance? I'm a total beginner :D

Any example code would be awesome!

Thanks,
Elijah

Comment: To add to the below, your classes should always inherit from NSObject (unless you have a very good reason not to), as this is needed for things like memory management.Also, you might want to check a beginner's obj-c to get an overview of this kind of stuff. There's a good one at http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Comment: @Chris: Though your advise is perfectly valid, yet I am not sure what made you think he is not inheriting from NSObject? He certainly didn't include the code of header file of `PtyView`. Nevertheless, it is good point to remember.

Comment: Ah. Didn't see the category on PtyView. That'll teach me for doing this right after getting up.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-(void)startTask;` appears to be private implementation and in theory should not be called from external classes.

To answer your question, you can call it something like this:

```
PtyView *v = [[PtyView alloc] init];
[v startTask];
[v release];
```

Though you will get a warning saying, `PtyView` might not respond to `startTask`. Since it is not in public interface of class.

**Update**: Above code assumes that when `startTask` returns, you are done with this object. But something tells me that you might be using async callbacks. If that is the case then `startTask` might return immediately and you won't release it then and there. Normally in this case, you will be notified by `PtyView` about the completion of task. So you release it when the task is complete.

**Update2**:
Making a method public is easy. You just declare it in the public interface (the header file of class):

```
//in PtyView.h
@interface PtyView
-(void)startTask;
@end

//in PtyView.m
@implementation PtyView
...
-(void)startTask {
//starts task
}
@end
```

Notice that there is no category defined in the interface declaration.

Comment: How would I then make startTask public?

Answer (score 0):

`self` represent the current object.

You just need to call the method like that.

```
[self startTask];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about subclassing ECHOAppDelegate? (Then make sure PtyView inherits from NSObject?)

```
// cf. http://amath.colorado.edu/pub/mac/programs/PseudoTTY.zip

@interface ECHOAppDelegate : PtyView
...
@end

@implementation ECHOAppDelegate
- (id) init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (!self) return nil;
   ...
   return self;
}

...
   [self startTask];
...
@end
```